# Help with vector equations

Tags: linear-algebra

https://gyazo.com/3909bada4452f1ac9c47088274b4c1fa

Give the vector equation for the line through the point (0,0,2) that is parallel to the line (-5t,-4-5t,-2):

L(t) = ?

Can someone show me how to do this step by step please?

Comment: Please type out images. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This will probably get closed on MSE, but you may find [this page](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/lineplane/lineplane.html) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the direction vector of your line $(-5t, -4-5t, -2)$ is just $(-5t, -5t, 0)$ so your desired line is just $(0-5t, 0-5t,2+0) = (-5t, -5t, 2)$.